# Iterating over dataframe returns only column headers

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, plot

I'm trying to extract the latitude, longitude, magnitude and times from a csv which contains data from Earthquakes, in order to plot them into a map.

My current code for the extraction of the data is:

```
import pandas as pd

csv_path = 'https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_hour.csv'
filename = pd.read_csv(csv_path, names = ['time','latitude','longitude','mag'])
lats, lons = [], []
magnitudes = []
timestrings = []

for row in filename:
    print (row)
    lats.append(row[1])
    lons.append(row[2])
    magnitudes.append(row[2])
    timestrings.append(row[0])

# Printing this to check if the values are correctly imported
# This is, instead, printing the second letter of each word
print('lats', lats[0:5])
print('lons', lons[0:5])
```

But my output is:

```
time
latitude
longitude
mag
lats ['i', 'a', 'o', 'a']
lons ['m', 't', 'n', 'g']
```

I'm sorry if this question was answered before, I tried to look it up but I didn't manage to get the answers I found working into my code.

Comment: `filename` is a pandas dataframe. It's not a file. Perhaps you were looking for a `csv.reader()` object instead?

Comment: If I change the code to:
"csv_data = csv.reader(filename)

for row in csv_data:...." I get "File ------- line 12, in <module>
    lats.append(row[1])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: `csv.reader()` takes a *file object* or iterable. Not a filename.

Comment: Iterating over a `pd.DataFrame` yields the names of it's *columns*.

Comment: Now I see the difference. I'm still having a hard time with all subtleties like this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a pandas dataframe, not a file. Iteration over a dataframe gives you the *headers of the series*:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> filename = pd.read_csv('https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_hour.csv', names = ['time','latitude','longitude','mag'])
>>> list(filename)
['time', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'mag']
```

Those names are the ones you passed into the `read_csv` call, but they are not a filter. I'd not use `names` *at all* here, and let Pandas figure out what columns there are, then pick from those:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_hour.csv')
>>> df.time
0    2017-09-12T22:13:27.650Z
Name: time, dtype: object
>>> df.latitude
0    58.0241
Name: latitude, dtype: float64
>>> df.longitude
0   -32.3543
Name: longitude, dtype: float64
>>> df.mag
0    4.8
Name: mag, dtype: float64
```

I used a more common `df` name to reflect this is a dataframe.

There is just one row, so you can get your data by converting each series to a list, producing single values:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_hour.csv')
time = df.time.tolist()
lats = df.latitude.tolist()
longs = df.longitude.tolist()
magnitudes = df.mag.tolist()
```

However, if you wanted to plot data, you could do so simply directly from the dataframe, without manually extracting lists. See [Pandas Visualisation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html).

Comment: Or better yet, just keep the dataframe intact!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I linked to the visualisations tutorial now.

Comment: Thank you very much again for the attention! I managed to get it working with all the help, but your post was the eureka one! Definitely learned a lot on the way to solving this problem.